# Heroku asset compile not working with Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I feel like I have exhausted my resources trying to figure this out. I have yet to run into this error with a heroku/rails app before and am simply puzzled as to why my js/css isnt being compiled/uploaded to Heroku.

As stated in the heroku docs your options are to:
1. Compiling assets locally.
2. Compiling assets during slug compilation.

I tried the first option: ran RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile, added public/assets and saw the "Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally" line when deploying. No CSS.

I tried the second option (clean git checkout before assets:precompile). Added the 'config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false' line as suggested for rails 3.x apps. And instead of seeing the expected:

```
Compiled jquery.js
Compiled jquery_ujs.js
Compiled application.js
Compiled application.css
```

etc etc

I get 'DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!' warnings. yet that folder is completely empty

Looked into this warning with no sign of it being the root cause for this. Feels like I'm going in circles so I am hoping someone has insight. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku docs suggests that add 'rails_12factor' gem to gemfile. Precompling assets before pushing to heroku is not required. And you also must use Heroku's cedar stack only.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The error ended up being a result of the bootstrap gem and application.css having conflicts